# How to get age of person and put it on dataGrid at run time without save it in database?

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm working in C# application, I have a `dataGridViewX1` which has a column called `Birthday` with an index number [3].

I want to add a new column at runtime to `dataGridViewX1` called `Age` with an index number [17].

How do I calculate the age and put it in column `Age`. I did this code but the error appears to me and said

> Column cannot be added because its CellType property is null.

CellType is (gets) not Gets or Sets. I Cant put a value to it, like below.

> col.CellType = typeof(int x)

This is my code:

```
DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
col.HeaderText = "Age";
col.Name = "ageBoD";
int colIndex = dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add(col);

DateTime brithday;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    brithday = (DateTime)dataGridViewX1[3, i].Value;
    TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - brithday;
    dataGridViewX1[17, i].Value = age.Days / 365;
}
```

If I did this code:

```
        DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();//This only has been changed.
        col.HeaderText = "Age";
        col.Name = "ageBoD";
        int colIndex = dataGridViewX1.Columns.Add(col);

        DateTime brithday;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            brithday = (DateTime)dataGridViewX1[3, i].Value;
            TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - brithday;
            dataGridViewX1[17, i].Value = age.Days / 365;

        }
```

the error is hide and gone, and the column has been added successfully . But another problem has been occur which is no data in that column.

Comment: Sorry about that you are right. I'll try to help find a solution. I am still new to C#

Comment: No problem, Dont be sorry, I'm new too. ^__^

Comment: Below i have found solution.

Comment: If you are still using the code above then copy the code below and replace your code in your program with it.

Comment: Are you using the exact code below ? If you are then display the birthday in the column and see if that is not null or reading the wrong column. Then tell me what you come up with

Comment: If your birthday is displaying wrong value that means it is getting a null value / empty string. That means the problem is with your columns not with the code i provided. try a 2 instead of a 3

Comment: We were trying to solve this shit problem before two hours and nothing is useful. I think I will delete it tomorrow. 
Sorry bro you were so kind person, thank you so much.

Comment: Well that was a waste then. It shouldn't be hard to find out what is wrong in your code. You have to find out why birthday is returning nothing.

Comment: It does not returning nothing, because I can see the results when I change the index to an exists index, and I used a Breakpoint.  Did you know the job of Breakpoint?!... I use it and it gives me the true value, the real problem is that the new column does not show the results.

Comment: I never used breakpoint before. And the code provided works. It reads from a column and writes the difference to a new column. Show me the code you are using.... What do you mean the true value ? Did you try to put anything in the value to make sure the code is working ? example: change this dataGridViewX1[column, i].Value = brithday.Year - DateTime.Now.Year; to this dataGridViewX1[column, i].Value = "Works";  Does it now display Works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this is worked for me

```
            DateTime brithday;
            DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
            col.HeaderText = "Age";
            col.Name = "ageBoD";
            col.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            int column = dataGridViewX1.Columns.Count;
            dataGridViewX1.Columns.Insert(column, col);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                brithday = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridViewX1[3, i].Value);
                dataGridViewX1[column, i].Value = brithday.Year - DateTime.Now.Year;
            }
```

Comment: I updated code it worked on mine. It did not add the birthdays but i did try adding strings and it worked.

Comment: That's what i got when i was trying to figure out the DateTime. It must mean that your DateTime has something wrong with it.

Comment: Is your DateTime Column formatted as DateTime ? if it is not you have to change the formatting or use a filter. You should ask a new question for that. They don't like multiple questions in one thread. Don't forget to mark this as solved when it is done.

Comment: Yes i know that i never used Timespan yet though. Not really sure how to fix that. You should mark this as solved and make a new question asking how to fix the TimeSpan issue.

Comment: The question was about the column problem. That question was solved as this creates the column.

Comment: OK, but let us wait till tomorrow, then I will

Comment: Try this it is working perfect on mine. Make sure you are counting rows correctly also. your 3 might have to be 2.

Comment: Post it above so i can see. Like i said mine is working perfect. It is something on your side that is wrong.

Comment: look!! if change the index of column as 16 which is already in my database it's works but it dose not work in the new column. I need that column with an index 16 and I dont want to replace it.

Comment: Are you copying my code exactly ??? If you are and the problem is the same then post a pic of your datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new column called `Team_Age` in database with an `int` as datatype.

Now, We will calculate the age at runtime without insert the data into database.

First step create a function that can show you the data in GridView, as

```
    public void showTeam()
    {
        //getting data from database and show it in GridView
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Team_ID],[Team_Age],[Team_Birthday]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dats = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(dats, "Team_Info");
        dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dats.Tables["Team_Info"];
        //the caculation start from here
        DateTime brithday;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            brithday = (DateTime)dataGridViewX1[2, i].Value;
            TimeSpan age = DateTime.Today - brithday;
            dataGridViewX1[1, i].Value = age.Days / 365;
        }
    }
```

Now, just call the function `showTeam()` as below:

```
    public TeamInfoForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showTeam();           
    }
```